# What is the difference between writing "::namespace::identifier" and "namespace::identifier"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, nested

I have seen both approaches in code. Could you explain what's the difference between the two? As I think it relates to the way namespace lookup is done by C++, could you provide some information on this as well, or perhaps a link to a good doc? Thanks.

Comment: It's like the difference between `/usr/bin/rm` and `usr/bin/rm`; or between `Windows\calc.exe` and `C:\Windows\calc.exe`.

Comment: Is it? If I declare a namespace and use the identifier "std::cout" it will still work - however there is no "std" namespace nested in my own namespace.

Comment: It means global scope. See Mark's answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213/scope-resolution-operator-without-a-scope

Comment: @DanNestor: Well, it's like that, plus the root directory is always in the search path, if you will :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, at least not most of the time.

In the format `::identifier1::identifier2`, the preceding colon says to look at global scope for `identifier1`, and then look for `identifier2` in that scope.

In the format `identifier1::identifier2`, we instead look at the *current* scope for `identifier1`. If we don't find it, then the parent scope is searched, and so on until we find it. We then search for `identifier2` within whatever scope we just found.

In the case where you're already at global scope, it won't matter. But that story changes when you're working within a namespace or classes that has other namespaces or classes nested within it.

Answer (score 12):

**Example:**

```
#include <cstdio>

namespace x {
    const int i = 1;
}

namespace y {
    namespace x {
        const int i = 2;
    }

    void func()
    {
        std::printf("x::i = %d\n", x::i);
        std::printf("::x::i = %d\n", ::x::i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    y::func();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
x::i = 2
::x::i = 1
```

**Explanation:**

- When you refer to an identifier like `x::i`, the definition used is the "closest" `x::i`.  Inside `::y::func`, the definition `::y::x::i` is closer than the definition `::x::i`.  By contrast, there is no such function `::y::std::printf` so `::std::printf` is used instead.
- When you refer to an identifier like `::x::i`, there is no possible ambiguity: it looks for a top-level namespace named `x`, then finds an `i` inside.

So using `::` at the beginning allows you to spell the full name of a global something.  This also allows you to distinguish between local and global variables.

**Example 2:**

```
#include <cstdio>
const int x = 5;
int main()
{
    const int x = 7;
    std::printf("x = %d\n", x);
    std::printf("::x = %d\n", ::x);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
x = 7
::x = 5
```

Comment: Why does "std::printf" work then, inside namespace "y"? There is no namespace "std" nested inside namespace "y". Could you please explain this bit as well?

Comment: @drandrestor: It's just like variable scoping - if the compiler doesn't find the name at the current level, it "pops" one level up and looks for it there. In this case the namespace `std` doesn't exists in `y`, so the compiler then checks the global namespace and find it there.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Ken Wayne VanderLinde seems to have mastered that particular art (see his gold badge).

Comment: I accepted Ken's answer because he explained exactly that if a namespace is not found in the current scope, the parent scopes will then be searched. Many thanks to Dietrich as well for a very detailed answer.