# Why is :: (scope) used with empty left-hand operand?

Tags: c++, scope, operator-keyword

I've seen this a few times now, and I've been scratching my head wondering why...

As an example: (http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=377394)

```
void LeftClick ( )
{  
  INPUT    Input={0};
  // left down 
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
  ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

  // left up
  ::ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
  ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

This example works without the :: (scope) operators so why are they even there?

Comment: It also works if `// left down` is removed. So why is it there? For clarity.

Comment: Assuming the OP is correct that it "works" even without the `::`, then yes, really. But I get that there's more to it, and this is why I didn't post as an answer.

Comment: It's commonly used in Windows, where MFC classes often have member functions with the same name as global API functions. Using :: tells us that you really intended to call the API function.

Comment: Is it? I never programmed much in Windows. Looks to me like yet another thing I could forget and screw something :-)

Comment: As I can't edit my previous comment to tenfour, my intention was saying that by adding useless `::`, your code gets more cluttered, not more clear.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This basically mean "get the GLOBAL scoped function, instead of the currently visible one".

```
void SendInput() { /* (1) */
}

namespace derp {
    void SendInput() { /* (2) */
    }

    void LeftClick() {
        ...
        ::SendInput(); /* matches (1) */
        SendInput();  /* matches (2) */
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case (it means global). It actually mean use an "Absolute Namespace Path" not a "Relative Namespace Path". It just happens to be a short path in this context and thus in the global namespace.

Comment: @LokiAstari Could you elaborate on the difference? Is it basically the same as referring to a file as `/path/to/file.txt` instead of `./path/to/file.txt` -- one is relative to the current position, the other is relative to a specific place? (in this case, the root folder)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: A good analog. But you also need to apply the PATH variable to make the analog better. A relative path will be searched for in every directory in the path (while an absolute one will not). In the C++ case the PATH is represented by every nested scope from the current position.  See  https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/bddbdc98e8c8b9da5edc This makes realative paths susceptible to new code being added in a parent namespace.

Comment: Does it have the same effect when used with classes ? `class Test : public ::OtherClass`

Comment: Yes @Winter (some characters)

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have the following:

```
void bar()
{
}

struct Foo
{
    void bar();
};
```

If you want to call the global function `bar` from the member function `Foo::bar` you use the syntax with empty left hand side:

```
void Foo::bar()
{
    // Call the global bar function, not recursively call myself
    ::bar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It forces an absolute name resolution.
Without it name resolution is searched for relative to the class(s)/functions namespace path.

So assume LeftClick() is in the namespace hierarchy:

```
namespace Level1
{
    namespace Level2
    {
        namespace Level3
        {
            LeftClick()
            {
                 ::SendInput();   // Absolute path only. SendInput in global namespace
                 SendInput();     // Relative path (Note resolved at compile time)
                                  //
                                  // Looks for the function here (in this order)
                                  //    ::Level1::Level2::Level3::SendInput()
                                  //    ::Level1::Level2::SendInput()
                                  //    ::Level1::SendInput()
                                  //    ::SendInput()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It becomes more interesting if you have a nested name:

```
namespace Level1
{
    namespace Level2
    {
        namespace Level3
        {
            LeftClick()
            {
                 ::Test::Action();  // Absolute Path: Function Action() 
                                    //                in namespace Test 
                                    //                in global namespace

                 Test::Action();    // Relative Path: Function Action()
                                    //                in namespace Test
                                    //                in current namespace path.
                                    //
                     // It will Look for Test (in this order)
                     // ::Level1::Level2::Level3::Test
                     // ::Level1::Level2::Test
                     // ::Level1::Test
                     // ::Test
                     //
                     // In the first Test (and only the first) it finds it will 
                     // try and resolve the Action() function. If it is not there
                     // it is a compile time error.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's to force the symbol to be looked up at global scope.

```
void foo() {} // 1

namespace A
{
    void foo() {} // 2

    void bar()
    {
        foo(); // 2
        ::foo(); // 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the scope operator in this fashion means that you are referring to the global scope.

To save me valuable time and keystrokes, check out [scope resolution operator without a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213/scope-resolution-operator-without-a-scope).

Answer (score 0):

The `::` is used to give  access  to an object directly from outside of the object.