# C++ new - memory substitution and scope resolution

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

I'm looking at the following code:

```
// operator new example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <new>          // ::operator new

struct MyClass {
  int data[100];
  int kk;
  MyClass(int ea) : kk(ea) {std::cout << "constructed [" << this << "]\n";}
};

int main () {

  std::cout << "1: ";
  MyClass * p1 = new MyClass(1);
      // allocates memory by calling: operator new (sizeof(MyClass))
      // and then constructs an object at the newly allocated space

  std::cout << "2: ";
  MyClass * p2 = new (std::nothrow) MyClass(2);
      // allocates memory by calling: operator new (sizeof(MyClass),std::nothrow)
      // and then constructs an object at the newly allocated space

  std::cout << "3: ";
  new (p2) MyClass(3);
      // does not allocate memory -- calls: operator new (sizeof(MyClass),p2)
      // but constructs an object at p2

  // Notice though that calling this function directly does not construct an object:
  std::cout << "4: ";
  MyClass * p3 = (MyClass*) ::operator new (sizeof(MyClass));
      // allocates memory by calling: operator new (sizeof(MyClass))
      // but does not call MyClass's constructor

  delete p1;
  delete p2;
  delete p3;

  return 0;
}
```

And I have two questions:

- Is the object 2 destroyed when executing the line

  ```
  new (p2) MyClass(3);
  ```

that should construct the object 3 in the object 2's allocated space?

- The line

  ```
  MyClass * p3 = (MyClass*) ::operator new (sizeof(MyClass));
  ```

also works without the ::, what's the purpose of the scope resolution operator used without a class/namespace before it?

Comment: Two questions should mean two questions.

Comment: I don't have my copy of the standard at arms reach, but I'd wager that the answer to your first question is no.

Comment: Your second question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213/scope-resolution-operator-without-a-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, no, the second object's destructor is not called. A new object is just initialized in its place. If you like, you can explicitly call the destructor of the object with `p2->~MyClass();` before you reuse its memory.

Secondly, the purpose of using `::` to qualify the allocation function is to make sure it comes from the global namespace. The standard implicitly defines two overloads of `operator new` for all translation units, and if you include `<new`>, you get a few extras. All of these are defined in the global namespace (not in `std`). It's possible to overload `operator new` for classes (simply provide them as member functions), so qualifying with `::` makes sure the global version is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Answer1: The object located at `p2`'s lifetime ends when you reuse it's memory for a new object. It won't have its destructor run so it's not "destroyed" cleanly, although with only POD members and no user-declared destructor, in this case it makes no difference.

Answer2: Using `::` forces the lookup for `operator new` to only consider `operator new` declared at global scope. In the scope which you are calling `operator new`, there is no other `operator new` that would be considered in any case, so it makes no difference.