# How access global function in class which is having same function signature as global function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Following is my scenario:

**file.h** This file contains two function with extern

```
extern int add(int a, int b);
extern int sub(int a, int b);
```

**file.cpp** Implementation of above functions.

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return 20;
}

int sun(int a, int b)
{
    return 20;
}
```

**test.h** This is class test in which two member function with same signature as extern add and sub in file.h

```
class test
{
    public:
          test();
          ~test();
    private:
         int add(int a, int b);
         int sub(int a, int b);
}
```

**test.cpp** Implementation of test class in test class constructor add function is called as well as both file are included.

```
#include "test.h"
#include "file.h" // Contains extern methods
#include <iostream>

test::test()
{
     int addition = add(10, 10);
     printf("Addition: %d ", addition );
}

int 
test::add(int a, int b)
{
    return 10;
}

int 
test::sub(int a, int b)
{
    return 10;
}
```

main.cpp

```
 #include "test.h"
 int main()
 {
   test *a = new test();
 }
```

Now my question is in main class what will be printed. Whether it will print

it giving output as 
     Addition : 10
Why it is giving `10` ? Is `class test` uses its own function `add()` and `sub()`. Because both function are present in `file.h` and same class. My guess was it will give `ambiguity` for functions. Is there any standard if so please explain. And **how can i use functions from file.h** in `class test`.

Comment: Obviously a compile error since you're trying to assign a pointer type to a non-pointer type here: `test a = new test();`

Comment: Nothing will get printed. Even if it compiled, you're not executing anything that prints anything. Just correct, compile and execute it.

Comment: The odds are pretty good that compiling the program and running it will provide an answer.

Comment: Why are you asking what the compiler will do, instead of compiling it yourself? If you don't have one on hand, there are [{online}](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) [{ones}](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: Run it and find out.

Comment: actually i want to ask question like this but in hurry i had posted partial question and got so may downvote :(  please check updated question.

Comment: @D'JayPatil Use `::add` to call the global `add` function.

Comment: @zenith yes it got it can you just post your comment in answer so that i can accept it as answer and cad upvote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `add` inside the `test` class will use the `add` member function.

To call the global `add` function use the [global scope resolution operator `::`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213/scope-resolution-operator-without-a-scope):

```
int addition = ::add(10, 10);
```

Comment: thank you ! can you send me the link where  i can get documentation of this.

Comment: @D'JayPatil Grab a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) and read it. The behaviour is described in the C++ standard, but most mortals don't want to read *that.*

Comment: @D'JayPatil Couldn't find an official doc but added a link to an SO question to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use can also do it using namespace.
in file.h

```
#include "file.h"
namespace file
{
     int add(int a, int b)
     {
         return 20;
     }

     int sub(int a, int b)
     {
         return 20;
     }
}
```

in test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "file.h" 
#include <iostream>

test::test()
{
     int addition = file::add(10, 10); // used namespace here
     printf("Addition: %d ", addition );
}

int 
test::add(int a, int b)
{
    return 10;
}

int 
test::sub(int a, int b)
{
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: using namespace i can i have multiple functions with same signature. right Uday